# Pytesseract return nothing in Urdu and Arabic text

Tags: python, ocr, arabic, python-tesseract, urdu

Converting Id Card Image to text by using Pytesseract. Till yet I've break the image in section for name address Id card number and parse it using

```
import pytesseract as tess
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("Image.jpg")
crop_rectangle = (20, 320, 400, 400)
cropped_im = im.crop(crop_rectangle)
text = tess.image_to_string(cropped_im, lang='ara')
print(text)
```

The result is blank.

In additional I've also tried 
`text = tess.image_to_pdf_or_hocr(cropped_im, lang='ara', extension='hocr')`

And this addition step returns

```
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"                
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<meta name=\'ocr-system\' content=\'tesseract v5.0.0-alpha.20191030\' />  
<meta name=\'ocr-capabilities\' content=\'ocr_page ocr_carea ocr_par ocr_line ocrx_word     
ocrp_wconf\'/>
</head>
<body>  
<div class=\'ocr_page\' id=\'page_1\' title=\'image     
"C:\\Users\\MOHSIN~1.IFT\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tess_za20zk94.PNG"; bbox 0 0 380 80; ppageno 0\'>  
<div class=\'ocr_carea\' id=\'block_1_1\' title="bbox 0 0 380 80">
<p class=\'ocr_par\' id=\'par_1_1\' lang=\'ara\' title="bbox 0 0 380 80">    
<span class=\'ocr_line\' id=\'line_1_1\' title="bbox 0 0 380 80; baseline 0 0; x_size 108;     
x_descenders 27; x_ascenders 27">     
<span class=\'ocrx_word\' id=\'word_1_1\' title=\'bbox 0 0 380 80; x_wconf 95\'> </span>    
</span>
</p>   
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>'
```

Need help to convert Urdu/Arabic Image into text 
Thank you in Advance

Comment: Hey, @ProgSMI were you able to solve this problem , I am facing the same issue.